# How can I draw LC resonant circuit frequency response in LTspice?

Tags: ltspice

I would like to create a frequency response graph of an LC resonant circuit, illustrating the attenuation (in dB) versus frequency.

[image]

The generated response seems inaccurate. It begins at 10 MHz and sweeps up to 1000 MHz, but unexpectedly ends at 1 Hz.

Additionally, the chart does not seem correct.

[image]

The ideal response should resemble something akin to this:

[image]

Could you assist me in identifying the error in my LTspice setup?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use Meg instead of M. M is translated to m, for milli

Comment: For large numbers I use their scientific notation, 1mega becomes 1E6, 1giga is 1E9, 1terra is 1E12, etc.